# bind_param inserindo número zero ao invés da string

Tags: php, sql, query, pdo

Ao invés de inserir a string, query insere na coluna description o número zero:

Código:

```php
$query = $db->prepare("UPDATE table_name SET tracker = ?, description = ? WHERE id = ?");
$query->bind_param("sis", $tracker, $description, $id);
$query->execute();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O problema estava no bind_param.

ao invés de

$query->bind_param("sss"... Ou seja, e strings

estava:

$query->bind_param("sis".... ou seja, String, inteiro, string